# Не могу войти в php myAdmin

Tags: php, linux, веб-программирование, phpmyadmin

Установил на mint: lamp,php,mysql,php_myAdmin.
всё вроде плучилось, даже сервер запустился.Нопри попытке входа в myAdmin- он говорит что нет прав.Логин я вводил root.Перепробовал все пароли:
Который вводил при установке, 123, toor - но всё без толку((

вот ошибка:
mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/1698): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'

Comment: У вас ошибка подключения поделки называемой phpMyAdmin к базе данных. Вам нужно посмотреть конфиги внимательней и убедится что логин/пароль который наверняка прописан в конфиге myadmin совпадает с тем логином/паролем (имеется в виду логин для root конечно же) который вы устанавливали для базы данных в процессе установки.  Я, кстати говоря,  не уверен что mysql позволяет оставлять пустой пароль для root. В любом случае проверьте внимательно.
Еще раз. У вас должен быть root пароль на БД, он же должен быть указан в myadmin

Comment: Не помогло, в конфигах нет ничего про пароль или логин(

Comment: Проверьте разрешён ли Remote access (удалённое подключение) для рута. Если нет, заходите в консоль MySQL и создавайте нового пользователя со всеми нужными Вам правами.

Answer (score 0):

По дефолту пароль должен быть пустой.